# LSTM predict pollution giving the future atmospheric data

Tags: python, keras, lstm, forecast

So i am working in this example (I believe many people have seen him): https://machinelearningmastery.com/multivariate-time-series-forecasting-lstms-keras/

This example use atmospheric(temperature, wind, etc) data to predict the pollution for the next day.

I use the same columns for atmospheric data and historic for 7 previous days to forecast.

But one big thing is missing in this example and I can't figure it out how to do it, that is, ok use the 7 previous days to predict tomorrow pollution, but I want to put the atmospheric data of the day of tomorrow to predict the pollution to!

This question can be applied to every forecast where weather variables are used, but i can't figure it out and can't find anyone with this question or solution.

**Resume:
I want to predict tomorrow pollution using the last 7 days of data (where I have pollution data also of this 7 days)[This I have], and append the atmospheric data of the day to forecast.**

(Believe I've search all internet (maybe I am really bad with google search :/ ), )

Comment: well, I ended up appending the pollution data for the day I want to predict directly. In fact I didn't observe bigger difference on results, but I think it's important to have them there :D